# Operaciones Javascript

Tags: javascript, html5, ajax, css3

tengo dos campos tipo date que me calculan la suma entre meses y el resultado lo imprime en un tercer input con nombre cantidad de meses en forma automática al seleccionar la fecha entre los datepicker. Quisiera saber como podría capturar ese resultado de cantidad de meses y multiplicarlo por el valor de otro input que esta definido con un valué por defecto = 300000, una vez realizada esta operación el resultado se divide por 12, por ultimo el resultado general imprimirlo en un input nuevo llamado total a pagar.
¿como podría realizar dicho código con JQuery y HTML?

funcion js

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function GetDays() {

var dropdt = new Date(document.getElementById("dep").value);
var pickdt = new Date(document.getElementById("arr").value);
var months = dropdt.getMonth() - pickdt.getMonth() + (12 * (dropdt.getFullYear() - pickdt.getFullYear())); if(dropdt.getDate() < pickdt.getDate()){ months--; } return months;
}

function cal() {
  if (document.getElementById("dep")) {
    document.getElementById("meses").value = GetDays();
  }
}
```

Codigo html

```
Inicio <input id="arr" type="date" name="arr" onchange="cal()" class="form-control">

Fin <input id="dep" type="date" name="dep" onchange="cal()" class="form-control">

meses   <input type="text" class="form-control total" id="meses" readonly>

se multiplica por este campo <input type="text" class="form-control total" id="valor" readonly value="300000"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes agregar un evento `onchange` tambien al mes y agregar la funcion del calculo del total, recuerda que como el evento no es manual después de cambiar el valor de meses tienes que hacer `trigger` programado del evento con `dispatchEvent`:

```js
    
    
    function GetDays() {
        var dropdt = new Date(document.getElementById("dep").value);
        var pickdt = new Date(document.getElementById("arr").value);
        var months = dropdt.getMonth() - pickdt.getMonth() + (12 * (dropdt.getFullYear() -          pickdt.getFullYear())); if(dropdt.getDate() < pickdt.getDate()){ months--; } return months;
    }
    
    function cal() {
        if (document.getElementById("dep")) {
            var el = document.getElementById("meses");
        el.value = GetDays();
        el.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
        }
    }
    
    function getvalue() {
        var meses = document.getElementById("meses").value;
        var valor = document.getElementById("valor").value;
        
        var result = ( meses * valor ) / 12;
        document.getElementById("total").value = result;
    }
```

```html
    Inicio <input id="arr" type="date" name="arr" onchange="cal()" class="form-control"><br>
            
    Fin <input id="dep" type="date" name="dep" onchange="cal()" class="form-control"><br>
            
    meses   <input type="text" class="form-control total" onchange="getvalue()" id="meses" readonly><br>
            
    se multiplica por este campo <input type="text" class="form-control total" id="valor" readonly value="300000" ><br>
        
    Total a Pagar   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="total" readonly><br>
```

Comment: Muchas, gracias pero no me muestra el resultado :( !

Comment: @Codej puede ser que tengas algun error en tu codigo; ya que lo he usado de ejemplo ...

Comment: @Codej ya solucione el problema en mi respuesta y como veras en tu código falta el despachador de evento...

Comment: Totalmente , ya me funciona correctamente , eternamente agradecido

Comment: Oye me surgió otra duda , agregue un combobox que me carga valores al input valor por el que se multiplica todo esto lo hace dinámicamente  según cada selección de letra A, b o C  todo bien hasta ahí, como cambio la sintaxis para que al momento de seleccionar una letra que contiene el valor del input por el que se multiplica me actualice el resultado en tiempo real dependiendo la seleccion que yo realice ya sea , A, b o c ya que solo me actualiza si solo cambio las fechas y debe actualizarce segun la opcion

Comment: @Codej crea otro post y en comentario agregas mi nombre

Comment: Como hago eso? soy bastante nuevo en esta plataforma

Comment: @Codej arriba a la derecha debes tener un boton que dice formular una pregunta ... le das click y hay redactas la pregunta nueva..

Comment: Pero como pongo tu nombre ?

Comment: Ya que ya hice el post